# R geom_bar conditional red green for positive/minus

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

First post on here and new to R so apologies for failure to follow any conventions...
I am trying to create combined bar/dot to show difference from a benchmark and highlight Red where value is less than a value in ref col and Green where value is greater than value. The differences have already been worked out and I am using a reference column to determine fill colour.

This isn't working out. 1) because the colours are the wrong way round (e.g. Green in my data results in Red in my bar. And 2) the colours aren't consistent. In a1 bar I have red and green bars but in b1 because I only have negative values, the colours change and where Red in a1 was filling positive values, in b1 it fills negative values.

What i would really like to know is how to rewrite my code below that ensures Red for negative values and Green for positive. I would really appreciate if you could tell me how adjust my code to do this!

Thanks,
Adam

This is `a1`

[image: a1 bar chart using data and code]

and this is `b1`

[image: b1 bar chart using data and code]

```
test <- (Test)
a1 <- filter(test, school =="a1")
a1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = diff, fill = diff_col, y = ques)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', alpha = .6, width = .2)+
  geom_point(aes(x = diff_sect, colour = sect_diff_col, y = ques, size = 3))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  facet_grid(~cah, labeller=label_wrap_gen(width=10))

b1 <- filter(test, school =="b1")

b1 %>% 
  ggplot (aes(x = diff, fill = diff_col, y = ques)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', alpha = .6, width = .2)+
  geom_point(aes(x = diff_sect, colour = sect_diff_col, y = ques, size = 3))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  facet_grid(~cah, labeller=label_wrap_gen(width=10))
```

The data I am using:

```
structure(list(school = c("a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", 
"b1", "b1", "b1", "b1", "b1", "b1"), cah = c("aa", "aa", "aa", 
"bb", "bb", "bb", "cc", "cc", "cc", "dd", "dd", "dd"), ques = c("q1", 
"q2", "q3", "q1", "q2", "q3", "q1", "q2", "q3", "q1", "q2", "q3"
), diff = c(12, 3, -10, 22, 33, 20, -12, -21, -15, -5, -6, -7
), ci = c(11, 11, 11, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4), diff_col = c("Green", 
"Red", "Red", "Green", "Green", "Green", "Red", "Red", "Red", 
"Red", "Red", "Red"), diff_sect = c(6, -8, -17, 18, 19, 12, -15, 
-29, -19, 3, 5, 5), sect_diff_col = c("Red", "Red", "Red", "Green", 
"Green", "Green", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Green", "Green"
)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(school = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), cah = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), ques = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), diff = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), ci = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), diff_col = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), diff_sect = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), sect_diff_col = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want your colours to come directly from the text in the `sect_differ_col` variable ("Red", "Green", ...). To do so, you can convert "Red" and "Green" to R colour names "red" and "green" using the `tolower` function. Then set your colour scale to `scale_colour_identity()`. For example:

```r
a1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = diff, fill = diff_col, y = ques)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', alpha = .6, width = .2)+
  geom_point(aes(x = diff_sect, colour = tolower(sect_diff_col), y = ques, size = 3))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  facet_grid(~cah, labeller=label_wrap_gen(width=10)) + 
  scale_colour_identity()
```

Comment: Many thanks! Will this work for the geom_bar as well?

Comment: I ask because I am referencing two different variables for colours. One for geom_point in sect_diff_col and the same principal applied to the geom_bar for diff_col.

Comment: try this to edit your bars according to the color column:
a1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = diff, fill = tolower(diff_col), y = ques)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', alpha = .6, width = .2)+
  geom_point(aes(x = diff_sect, colour = tolower(sect_diff_col), y = ques, size = 3))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  facet_grid(~cah, labeller=label_wrap_gen(width=10)) + 
  scale_colour_identity()

Answer (score 0):

ggplot automatically sets the colors according to the factors within the group you provide. So, if you don't provide factors, it makes the best it can. Transform your grouping columns by:

```
test <- (Test)

test$diff_col <- factor(test$diff_col, levels = c("Red", "Green"))
test$sect_diff_col <- factor(test$diff_col, levels = c("Red", "Green"))

a1 <- filter(test, school =="a1")
a1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = diff, fill = diff_col, y = ques)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', alpha = .6, width = .2)+
  geom_point(aes(x = diff_sect, colour = sect_diff_col, y = ques, size = 3))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  facet_grid(~cah, labeller=label_wrap_gen(width=10))

b1 <- filter(test, school =="b1")

b1 %>% 
  ggplot (aes(x = diff, fill = diff_col, y = ques)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', alpha = .6, width = .2)+
  geom_point(aes(x = diff_sect, colour = sect_diff_col, y = ques, size = 3))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  facet_grid(~cah, labeller=label_wrap_gen(width=10))
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but I have tried and I can't make this work. Is there any chance you can show how to incorporate that in the code I supplied with my question?

Comment: Appreciate your help. This works but when I try to copy/paste the code and use on other subsets of the data (e.g. c1, d1 etc) the colours for the bars sometimes reverse (i.e. positive becomes red). Do you know why this might be and is there any way to make it consistent every time I reuse the code?

Comment: I am not sure, why it does not work for other groups (make sure, the columns diff_col and sect_diff_col are again factors). You could try to include this line of code into your ggplot: scale_fill_manual(values=c("red",  "green"))

Comment: It works now, it must have been something I was doing wrong. You've been a great help, thank you.

Comment: Actually, I think the issue is that when there are no negative values in a subset, (so no reds), the colour chosen for positives changes to red. Do you have any idea of how to prevent this?

Comment: *One solution is where there are only positive values define as: scale_fill_manual(values=c("green"))

Answer (score 0):

First of all, R is case sensitive and `"Green"` is not the same as `"green"`. The same goes for `"Red"` and `"red"`.
Then, the values green and red are not assigned to positive and negative values, respectively, of the numeric variables.
Finally, the colours' names in `aes()` do *not* correspond to colours of those names, the names in `aes()` are just a way to tell different colours are to be used. The solution is to set the colours manually with a `scale_colour_*` or `scale_fill_*`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

clrs <- setNames(c("green", "red"), c("green", "red"))

test %>%
  filter(school == "a1") %>%
  mutate(diff_col = ifelse(diff >= 0, "green", "red"),
         sect_diff_col = ifelse(diff_sect >= 0, "green", "red")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = diff, fill = diff_col, y = ques)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', alpha = 0.6, width = 0.2)+
  geom_point(aes(x = diff_sect, colour = sect_diff_col, y = ques, size = 3))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = clrs) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = clrs) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  facet_grid(~cah, labeller = label_wrap_gen(width = 10))
```

[image]

And now for `"b1"`.

```
test %>%
  filter(school == "b1") %>%
  mutate(diff_col = ifelse(diff >= 0, "green", "red"),
         sect_diff_col = ifelse(diff_sect >= 0, "green", "red")) %>%   ggplot (aes(x = diff, fill = diff_col, y = ques)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', alpha = 0.6, width = 0.2)+
  geom_point(aes(x = diff_sect, colour = sect_diff_col, y = ques, size = 3))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0)+
  scale_colour_manual(values = clrs) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = clrs) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  facet_grid(~cah, labeller=label_wrap_gen(width=10))
```

[image]

As it can be seen, the code is *exactly the same*, only varying the `school` value. This can, therefore, be simplified to the following `lapply` loop and plot afterwards.

```
Schools <- c("a1", "b1")
gg_plots_list <- lapply(Schools, function(x){
  test %>%
    filter(school == x) %>%
    mutate(diff_col = ifelse(diff >= 0, "green", "red"),
           sect_diff_col = ifelse(diff_sect >= 0, "green", "red")) %>%   ggplot (aes(x = diff, fill = diff_col, y = ques)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', alpha = 0.6, width = 0.2)+
    geom_point(aes(x = diff_sect, colour = sect_diff_col, y = ques, size = 3))+
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0)+
    scale_colour_manual(values = clrs) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = clrs) +
    theme_bw()+
    theme(legend.position = "none")+
    facet_grid(~cah, labeller=label_wrap_gen(width = 10))
})
names(gg_plots_list) <- Schools
```

Now this produces the 1st plot above.

```
gg_plots_list[["a1"]]
```